# Ajax call data unable to access in classic asp

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp-classic

I am unable to access data in classic asp file sent from the jquery ajax call.

Here is my ajax call

```
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
  url: "mymessage.asp?phone=" + $( "#mobile1" ).val() + "&message=" + $('textarea#message').val(),
    data:{ 

   phone: $( "#mobile1" ).val(),
   message: $('textarea#message').val()

   },
  contentType: "text/html; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "text",
  success: function(msg) {
    // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
    alert(msg);

  }
});
```

I am accessing the request values from asp page as

```vb
<%Request.Form("phone")%>
```

and

```vb
<%Request.Form("message")%>
```

but its not working.

I have debugged using Firefox firebug. The request is hitting the mymessage.asp page but I'm unable to access the request variables in the classic asp file

I am fed up after long search and various trial and hit methods.  What is actually going wrong??  Please help.

P.S: there is nothing wrong in the data values as I have  printed using console.log and data values are fine. Problem is with accessing the data in classic asp code.  You can also see I kept both data and appended URL (although I tried them individually still not working)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are passing those values to asp page as querystring ( `mymessage.asp?phone=" + $( "#mobile1" ).val() + "&message=" + $('textarea#message').val()` ), you can not retrieve those values using `Request.Form`, as it is a `GET` request not `POST` Request. Also if you look into `ajax` method ,it is Get method - `type: "GET",`.

To access those values , you need to use `Request.QueryString` .

e.g. `<%Request.QueryString("phone")%>`

Read this - [Difference between Request.Form and Request.QueryString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20697272/difference-between-request-form-and-request-querystring)

Comment: Or change `type: "POST"`, in fact I would do this rather then passing values as "GET" requests.

Comment: @Lankymart, in that case, for clarification sake, OP has to remove value from Querystring, as it is already passing through `data: {}`

Comment: Absolutely let's be honest it's a mess. The OP should be not be passing querystring on the URL regardless of whether ajax request is a `GET` or `POST`, passing `data: {}` on a `GET` will get transformed to a querystring automatically no need to pass it manually like that. Allows for much easier switching between `GET` and `POST` requests.

Comment: Not sure about that link it's the not the best...is there not a better quality one?

Answer (score 1):

[@ArindamNayak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/932584/arindam-nayak) is [absolutely right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26959421/692942).

### GET and POST Knowing the Differences

HTTP `GET` requests passes the data as a serialised string of parameters separated by ampersand (`&`) delimiters appended to the request URL, also known as a querystring.

HTTP `POST` requests pass the data in the body of the request as serialised string of parameters in the same form as a `GET` querystring.

Classic ASP makes it easy to access these values with two collections

### Request Collections

- **Request.QueryString()** - Contains all parameters requested via the `GET` request method.
- **Request.Form()** - Contains all parameters requested via the `POST` request method.
- **Request()** - Contains all parameters requested via either the `GET` or `POST` request methods.

  **NOTE:** - This method is less efficient because the parameter has be checked in both the `QueryString` and `Form` collections, if you know where your data is coming from *(whether it's a `GET` or `POST` request)* it is best to use the corresponding collection.

---

### Example Usage

If the following request is made

```
GET http://example.com/default.asp?phone=123456&message=test HTTP/1.1
```

In the page `default.asp` the parameters can be accessed using either the `Request.QueryString()` or `Request()` collections.

```vb
<%
  Dim message

  'Retrieves parameter from Request.QueryString collection.
  phone = Request.QueryString("message")
  'Checks both Request.Form and Request.QueryString.
  phone = Request("message")

  Response.Write phone 'Returns "test"
%>
```

If the following request is made

```
POST http://example.com/default.asp HTTP/1.1

phone=12345&message=test
```

In the page `default.asp` the parameters can be accessed using either the `Request.Form()` or `Request()` collections.

```vb
<%
  Dim message

  'Retrieves parameter from Request.Formcollection.
  phone = Request.Form("message")
  'Checks both Request.Form and Request.QueryString.
  phone = Request("message")

  Response.Write phone 'Returns "test"
%>
```

### What About jQuery Ajax Requests?

jQuery makes a really easy to pass this information, the three properties you want to make sure are set correctly are;

- **url** - The URL we are sending data to, do not include the querystring just the absolute / relative path to the Classic ASP page.
- **type** - Either `GET` or `POST` depending on the intended request method.
- **data** - The data we are sending to the URL. If it is `type: "GET"` the data will be automatically serialised and attached during the AJAX request as a URL querystring.

Using my previous example the AJAX request would look something like this;

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://example.com/default.asp",
  data: {
    phone: "12345",
    message: "test"
  }
});
```

will create a RAW HTTP request like

```
GET http://example.com/default.asp?phone=12345&message=test HTTP/1.1
```

and in the Classic ASP page `default.asp` you can access the parameters using something like;

```vb
<%
  Dim phone, message
  phone = Request.QueryString("phone")
  message = Request.QueryString("message")
%>
```

---

### Useful Links

- [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Also of note, if you are not using an SSL but you are using GET instead of POST you are ripe for a man in the middle attack on your data, so if you require passing data through a url be sure you are encrypting that connection and not just encrypting the data values themselves.

Comment: Absolutely agree, but this isn’t specific to Classic ASP. It would apply to any HTTP server-based web application.